# Angular: alternative to injecting services using the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

All examples I found, injected a service like this:

```
export class TestComponent {

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private dataService2: DataService2,
    private dataService3: DataService3,
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
  ) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

However, this list can get very long and confusing if you inject several services and also use the constructor method to initialize something.
So the question is:
**Can I write this alternatively?**

```
export class TestComponent {

  private dataService = new DataService();
  private dataService2 = new DataService2();
  private dataService3 = new DataService3();

  constructor() {
        // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: No. The top example is the only way to inject services. Also, doing it the second way is just as cluttered. Either way you have a list of things. It doesn't really look much different, honestly.

Comment: What happens when you have services that depend on other services? Are you going to new those up each time, too? Unit testing would be out the window, too. You think the list in the constructor is long and confusing? You would know a new form of pain by going down the second road you describe.

Comment: These are oranges and apples. dataService will be singleton in snippet 1 and won't be in 2. And I don't see how snippet 2 is better. It's just different. dataService is hard-coded to be DataService instance (it's unnecessarily will be when it's injected with DI).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly your service need to do.
If it just a bunch of usefull methods, you can do it, but in every component where u write somthing like this `private dataService = new DataService();` u will get new instance of service.

on the other hand, in my work we often use Services as data storages, to query something from it, with this `new` keyword u will instantiate it and won't get any data that were passed from another component.

Anyways DI is a great part of Angular ecosystem. So u can declare it into providers on modules (before that separate your components to rely on some module) that are actually using them to lower its quantity into app module.
Because if you inject som many stuff into 1 component constructor better to separate some functionality, because it may become really ugly.